# Existe incompatibilidade e erros entre Internet explorer e PostgreSQL?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, internet-explorer

Em meu trabalho nós utilizamos o PostgreSQL versão 9.0 como banco de dados para diversos sistemas. Alguns clientes nos informam que as vezes não conseguem encontrar determinados dados de pesquisas utilizando o Internet Explorer 9, 10 e 11. Eu como desenvolvedor utilizo o Firefox e as vezes o Chrome e nunca consigo achar esses erros. Acredito que haja alguma incompatibilidade desse banco de dados com o IE mesmo. Isso é verídico? Há mesmo um problema de compatibilidade como IE?

Comment: Atualmente a sua pergunta está bem vaga, não disse a versão do IE e Postgres que é usada, não sabe quais os erros, é difícil alguém responder sua pergunta de forma objetiva. Dê uma olhada em [**Como fazer uma boa pergunta?**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: opa, obrigado por notar isso já alterei ali com as versões.

Comment: Isso tem cara de ser incompatibilidade do navegador com algum javascript, use o console do IE para descobrir mais detalhes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Banco de dados não influencia o browser que o cliente está utilizando, o que pode estar influenciando são os arquivos Javascript que estão sendo carregados na página. Alguma função pode ser compatível com um navegador mas não com o outro, como é o caso do Internet Explorer como você está falando.

O banco de dados fica presente do lado do servidor, quem é responsável por gerenciar as configurações de driver pode ser um servidor como o Tomcat, Wilfly ou Apache (caso utilize PHP), portanto não há incompatibilidade entre o navegador que pertence ao lado do cliente com o PostgreSQL ou outro banco que pertence ao lado do servidor. Ficou claro? Qualquer dúvida estamos aqui.

Answer (score 4):

O problema certamente está na forma como a pesquisa é feita. Você não está encontrando diferenças nos resultados apresentados dependendo da marca do navegador. Está encontrando diferenças dependendo de quem está usando o sistema.

Até é possível ter dados diferentes sendo apresentados em navegadores diferentes, mas aí mostra que suas páginas são mais complexas do que deveriam e são pouco testadas. Não estou dizendo que você tem este problema, digo apenas que é possível, embora altamente improvável. Se acha que pode ser isto, que tem alguma coisa na página que pode estar ocultando dados no IE, abra uma pergunta específica e mostre seu código que você acha que está fazendo isto. Não tem como analisarmos sem ver código. Mas reforço que é improvável que tenha algum problema.

Mas respondendo sua pergunta objetivamente incompatibilidade entre o banco de dados e qualquer navegador não porque eles sequer conversam entre si.

De qualquer forma você pode testar isto facilmente. Use o IE e veja se muda alguma coisa. E/ou mande seus clientes testar com outro navegador (eu sei que isto é um pouco mais complicado de fazer dependendo do cliente) e o resultado será o mesmo. Ou seja, eu descartaria de cara qualquer problema com o navegador mas faça o teste para ter certeza, não tem forma melhor de descobrir.

Por último você pode ainda estar curioso sobre o problema. Se realmente há um problema e não há um erro de interpretação dos dados por parte dos clientes ou por você, provavelmente o erro está na aplicação do lado do servidor. Provavelmente sob certas circunstâncias ela recupera os dados de um jeito ou de outro.

O navegador pode influenciar nisto? Sim, pode, mas de novo é altamente improvável. Sua aplicação precisaria tratar os dados de forma diferente dependendo da informação de qual navegador o usuário está usando sendo capturado através de JavaScript e mandado para o servidor. Mas tudo isto é especulação e se fosse isto, você saberia.